# file upload with java-graphql Client with node.js apollo server

Tags: android, node.js, apollo-client, apollo-server, graphql-java

I'm creating a **web** app and **Android** app with **node.js apollo server** backend. And in my web app I'm using **react-apollo client** and for an android app using a **java-graphql client**.

For a web app, I've successfully done the image upload process with node apollo server.

But for the Android application, I'm stuck with it :(

I am surfing on the internet so far & still can't get a clear idea about how the images have to be uploaded from **android (java) client** to **Backend** (node.js apollo server)

Please help me to breathe out from this botch situation :(

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?